# Using a get variable while staying on the same page?

Tags: php, jquery

I was wondering if there is a way to use a GET variable while staying on the same page.

I have some php/mysql script that I would like to execute if a particular link is clicked, using a GET variable. However, once the link is clicked, I don't want anything on the page to change, I just want to the script to run behind the scenes.

Right now, when A user is on the search page and adds an item to their favorites all search results disappear, and b/c I am resubmitting

NOTE: The add to favorites link below, links to same page that the user will be on when clicking it.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
     echo '<div id="favbutton"><a href="search.php?id='.$id.'"><img src="./image/staricon.png"/>Add to favorites</a></div>';
}
```

thank you

Comment: Why don't you use an ajax call?

Comment: PHP is not event driven. If you want to perform some task according to user interaction you should use Javascript. You can use, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  .

Comment: You can follow the link that might help you http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: thanks for the responses guys, ill look into AJAX. 
Can someone possibly show me an example on how a simple AJAX GET function would work maybe?

Comment: @MHZ you can always Google for simple things. There are tons of articles, blog posts available on this topic. If you need serious technical advice/help stackoverflow is for you.

Comment: Okay ill do some reading and if I run into some trouble ill check back, thanks for the help everyone. :)

Comment: You say you don't want to refresh but what should happen when they click, is there anything visual that needs updating too

Comment: not at all. Maybe an alert message saying 'X added to favorites successfully'. Mostly everything that happens once the link is clicked should happen behind the scenes. If no alert message is displayed thats fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a .get() function that you can use to accomplish this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/. You can use it to pass any number of GET parameters to your server-side script. If that scripts returns any data, you can implement a callback to determine what to do with the data.

Here is an example of using jQuery .get(). One of the jQuery paradigms is "unobtrusive JavaScript", so it is standard to add event handlers in their own script rather than in the outdated onclick attribute. That said, here's a sample implementation:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickable").click(function(e) { // Gets all elements with a class of "clickable"
        $.get("myScript.php",
            { myGETVar: $(this).attr("src") }, // Passes the "src" of the clicked element as "myGETVar"
            function(returnedData) {
                alert("The script returned: " + returnedData);
            }, "html" // In this case we're expecting the script to return html
        );
    });
}
```

That is just a simple example, but it demonstrates how you can attach a click handler to any number of elements (in this case elements with class "clickable") and create an ajax request. This example passes the "src" of the clicked element (say you want to use this with images) and passes that to myScript.php as the GET variable "myGETVar".

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I dont understand how to use this if the get variable depends on the item clicked, the jquery script is in the header and the GET variable isn't defined yet? can you show me an example maybe?

Comment: I updated my comment to include an example. Is this the sort of thing that you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use ajax(JavaScript only) or [jQuery get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to do this.

Comment: Adam means "ajax AND jquery" ;) checkout the [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) functions

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AJAX and you can use do that easily using [jQuery.Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

You have to place a call silently into a server script to add that to favorites and then show user a message on success.